# Is it possible to inject a context into another context?

Tags: java, xml, spring, inheritance, applicationcontext

Maybe the question isn't that clear, but with an example, I guess I'll clear it out. In my project, I have two kinds of tests: integration tests and scenario tests. They both need a datasource (with a custom made propertyplaceholder).

In the context of the integration testcase, in only define the datasource and the placeholder, like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertyResolver" class="com.cegeka.bibliothouris.test.MultiThreadedPropertyResolver">
    <property name="location"><value>classpath:testContext.properties</value></property>
</bean>
```

In my scenario testcase context, I need these objects as well (together with some other stuff), but I just want to create an integration context 'in' my scenario context, so some kind of inheritance.

I've already tried it with a `classPathApplicationContext` in my scenario testcase (once with lazy-init on true),like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>classpath:overridingTestContext.xml</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

But he doesn't create a `dataSource` in the scenario context. This is a problem very hard to google, that's why I'm asking it here. I hope someone has the solution.

Comment: Why do you want to make it so complicated (two contexts)? Why do you not just refer the integration testcase configuration from the secenario test case configuration, and build one context?

Comment: I don't know what you excactly mean, I'm new to Spring, but the scenariotest needs to start a seleniumserver, a seleniumhost and a jettyserver, the integrationtest doesn't. So it isn't needed to start all those stuff when I run a integration test. And if there is need for some third testcase, which needs to use the datasource as well, I can import it there as well.

Comment: What Johan Sjöberg descibed in his answer is a way to build ONE Application Context out of two Configuration files -- That is what I have meant by the easy way (not just refer the integration testcase configuration from the secenario test case configuration, and build one context). What you have asked in your question (or what I have anderstund what you tries) was a bit different, you tried to have two different contexts where one can use the other (a bit like web- and application-context). -- Anyway: the answer of Johan Sjöberg is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring can combine several appicationcontexts and provides an inheritance-similar model by allowing only one bean with the same id. If two beans share the same id the latter will override the former.

Hence you can simply import the configs you need in the proper order using e.g.,

```
<import resource="context.xml" />
```

The behaviour does however depend on the value of 
 [setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.html#setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding%28boolean%29) which defaults to `true`.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I guess I just have to place it between my other beans? I did this: <import resource="classpath:overridingTestContext.xml"/>, but he still can't find a dataSource...

Comment: In my understanding spring parses one config file wholly before the next, hence it doesn't matter if you place the import statement between two beans. Also make sure you've specified the correct resource path (e.g., by debug-logging spring with log4j).

Comment: Hmm, I guess I've found the problem. Besides the integrationcontext and the scenariocontext, my testcases also need to inject an applicationcontext. It's not in the scenario context that he can't find a datasource, but it is in the applicationcontext. Which is actually very weird, because it works when I run an integration test, and it doesn't work when I run a scenario test.